# Remain iframe ratio but still be responsive and exploit screen width

Tags: html, css, reactjs, iframe, responsive

### **Usecase and problem**

Four livestreams as iframes are embedded on a webpage. I have used flexbox with flex-direction: row to positoin them next to each other. I want the page to be responsive and by this, the iframes have to keep their specific ratio but exploit the total width of the client-screen.
As a side-note, the camera producing the livestream is physically tilted 90 degrees, and because of this, the iframes have to be rerotated 90 degrees.

*I need some advice for the CSS.*

### **HTML - homepage react component**

```
import React from 'react'
import HomeCSS from './Home.module.css';

function Home() {
  return (
    <div className={HomeCSS.pageWrapper}>
      <div className={HomeCSS.upperbox}>

        <div className={HomeCSS.iframeWrapper}>
          <iframe className={HomeCSS.myiframe} src='https//foo.bar'></iframe>
        </div>

        <div className={HomeCSS.iframeWrapper}>
          <iframe className={HomeCSS.myiframe} src='https//foo.bar'></iframe>
        </div>

        <div className={HomeCSS.iframeWrapper}>
          <iframe className={HomeCSS.myiframe} src='https//foo.bar'></iframe>
        </div>

        <div className={HomeCSS.iframeWrapper}>
          <iframe className={HomeCSS.myiframe} src='https//foo.bar'></iframe>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div className={HomeCSS.lowerWrapper}>
        <div className={HomeCSS.lowerbox}>
          Fisheye
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

### **CSS**

```
.pageWrapper {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: blanchedalmond;
}

.upperbox {
    padding-top: .3%;
    padding-bottom: .3%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    gap: 3px;
    justify-content: space-around;
    height: fit-content;
}

.lowerWrapper {
    padding: .5%;
}

.lowerbox {
    border: 3px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: fit-content;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 70px;
}

.iframeWrapper {
    border: 3px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    min-height: 500px;
    min-width:300px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.myiframe {
    border-style: none;
    pointer-events: none;
    width: 185%;
    height: 150%;
    rotate: 90deg;
    position: absolute;
    left: -43%;
    top: -28%;
}
```

### **What I have tried**

I have thought of that the iframe-wrappers have to stretch to fit the width of the screen and afterwards expand the height to maintain the correct ratio. At the moment i found that a hardcoded ratio of height: 500px and width: 300px and the iframe itself a bit zoomed and shiftet to the left, looks good.

#### **Images**

Desired output (the iframes are maximizing the width of the window):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SWYp.png)

Actual output (When expanding the window, the iframes keep ratio but does not resize to the bigger screen-size.):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNLn8.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can force the aspect-ratio to always be 300 / 500 - unless of course the viewport dimensions are such that the minimum width and height requirements can't be met.

```css
.pageWrapper {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: blanchedalmond;
}

.upperbox {
  padding-top: .3%;
  padding-bottom: .3%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 3px;
  justify-content: space-around;
  height: fit-content;
}

.lowerWrapper {
  padding: .5%;
}

.lowerbox {
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: fit-content;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 70px;
}

.iframeWrapper {
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  min-height: 500px;
  min-width: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  aspect-ratio: 3 / 5;
}

.myiframe {
  border-style: none;
  pointer-events: none;
  width: 185%;
  height: 150%;
  rotate: 90deg;
  position: absolute;
  left: -43%;
  top: -28%;
}
```

```html
<div class="pageWrapper">
  <div class="upperbox">

    <div class="iframeWrapper">
      <iframe class="myiframe" src='https//foo.bar'></iframe>
    </div>

    <div class="iframeWrapper">
      <iframe class="myiframe" src='https//foo.bar'></iframe>
    </div>

    <div class="iframeWrapper">
      <iframe class="myiframe" src='https//foo.bar'></iframe>
    </div>

    <div class="iframeWrapper">
      <iframe class="myiframe" src='https//foo.bar'></iframe>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="lowerWrapper">
    <div class="lowerbox">
      Fisheye
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```